# typeerror cannot read property 'length' of undefined app script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, typeerror, undefined

Hi I am trying to use this code to import a JSON file from API
I keep getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

```
PIVOT_URL_Country = ""
SHEET_NAME_Country = "test"

function updateDataCountry() {
const response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(PIVOT_URL_Country))
const headers = [response.headers]
const data = response.report
const output = headers.concat(data)
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME_Country)
sheet.getDataRange().clearContent()
sheet.getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output)
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you console.log(output)? right after you declare it

Comment: Does response.headers have a length?  If it's [this object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers), then no it doesn't.

Comment: `headers` is an array (contains just one element), `data` is not an array (I suppose). If so, `const output = headers.concat(data)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's need to see an example of your JSON and the desired output to figure out what you have and if it's possible to concat or push or something else the values.

Comment: I would suggest wrapping everything in try catch blocks to be sure you catch any errors.  I would also suggest console.log() for `header`, `data`, and `output` to see what they really are.

Comment: You need to use the debugger and figure out what is happening with output